# What's the process on public beta?

Tags: support

Yesterday, I watched the counter at [Skeptics @ Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics) go from "The site's Public Beta will begin in 4 minutes", to "The site's Public Beta will begin soon", which is the status it's been in since.

What's the process for a site to reach public beta? Is there some automation, or does somebody make an objective call as to when the site is ready for it?

I don't really mind either way, I just thought the "4 minutes" thingy seemed to imply a very high precision, that it turns out didn't exist at all.

Comment: I was under the impression that the transition to public beta is automated, and only the graduation to full site is decided manually. I've tagged it also with bug as I think this is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: AS far as I know private to public beta is semi-manual, i.e. needs confirmation by SE staff. Source: SO Meta I think.

Comment: I disagree with the 'bug' tag/conclusion, as there is support for "it takes a while" in the whole interface: the status says *"The site's Public Beta will begin soon."*, just as it did when it went from proposal to beta: it seems to me this just takes a while? Now the fact that it is rather slow might be a bug, but the fact that it is not instantaneous looks like 'by design' I think.

Comment: @Nanne I've searched on Meta and found that it was similar for Code Review (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76595/why-is-code-review-se-still-in-private-beta), so I removed the bug tag again. It seems to be normal that it takes some time.

Comment: I don't at all mind that it's not exact. If there was a manual transition, I'd be fine with that. My reaction was mainly based on the fact that it at one point said that *will begin in 4 minutes*, which implies precision that weren't here. *That* might be considered a bug, or at least a design flaw.

Comment: I don't mind it not being 100% exact but they're almost 24h behind schedule now; that's why I'm curious of the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is now in Public Beta:

[image: Public beta for Skeptics Q&A site - Area 51 - Stack Exchange]